# How to Convert Binary from a TXT file in C /txt including only int/

Tags: c, binary, int, converters, txt2tags

The part of my code that I'm asking about looks like this.
My TXT is containing number from 1-20 divided by . I want to make a BINARY file
from this txt, that's what the program supposed to do, but it is only feeling it up with memory dirt. Can you tell me if my code has mistakes.

```
void txt_to_bin (void)                                 
{
FILE *ft,*fb;
int a;
ft = fopen("binadatok.txt","rt");
fb = fopen("versenyazonosito.dat","wb");
while (fscanf(ft,"%d\n",&a) != EOF)
{
    fprintf(fb,"%d\n");

}

}
```

Comment: You're not putting anything in the fprintf, which is why it is picking up memory dirt. It should probably be a compiler error. Also you're just putting the same thing in again.

Comment: I'm also going to say memory dirt from now on, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `fwrite` when writing to a binary file, not `fprintf`:

```
fwrite(&a, sizeof(a), 1, fb);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I really wonder that people are helping others for free.

Comment: However I think it is  fwrite(_&a_,sizeof(a),1,fb);

Answer (score 0):

you are not providing any value in fprintf(fb,"%d\n") you should provide input of a in this statement .

```
void txt_to_bin (void)                                 
{
FILE *ft,*fb;
int a;
ft = fopen("binadatok.txt","rt");
fb = fopen("versenyazonosito.dat","wb");
while (fscanf(ft,"%d\n",&a) != EOF)
{
    fprintf(fb,"%d\n",a);

}

}
```

now it will work.

Comment: yeah, that's a mistake too. glad you helped me out :)